# Jumping into an inner link without changing the address bar?

Tags: javascript, html

Usually people ask to change the address bar without refreshing, I want the opposite: I want to jump to an anchor in the page, e.g. having

```
<a name="foo">
```

and then achieve the same functionality as the user pressing

```
<a href="#foo">
```

without changing the address bar. This is purely cosmetic, but this means that suggestions like "set window.location again after you are done" won't help since the intermediate changes will still be noticeable (the address bar will flicker, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid).

Comment: Why?  This hurts the ability to link to sections of the page.  I do that all the time (including on this site).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the DOM function [`element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView). For your purposes, this would work something like this:

```
var target = document.getElementById('foo');
target.scrollIntoView();
```

You should also remove the `<a name="foo">` links, and replace them with any element with an id. For example:

```
<h1><a name="heading"></a>Heading</h1>

<h1 id="heading">Heading</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at , jquery ScrollTo plugin, http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: Please, `document.getElementById("id").scrollIntoView();` is 1 line of code, and doesn't require a several 1000 line-long lib, not to mention the extra plugins... case in point why jQuery should be avoided

Comment: However, if I'm using jQuery anyway, it might be a better way (not in this case, maybe, because of the plugin).